# How to pass automation test case data from TFS to Protractor using Cucumber/Jasmine

Tags: typescript, tfs, visual-studio-code, jasmine, protractor

I am using Visual Studio Code, Protractor, Typescript and Jasmine to build test cases from the Angular website. I need to pick test data from Team Foundation Server (TFS) only. It was possible in Coded UI with Visual studio. Just wondering if it's possible in case of Protractor as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you checked TFS REST api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0?